# codeigniter email keeps getting blocked

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, codeigniter-url, spam-prevention

Hi I have a problem with my script sending emails out.  It turns out that my host has a spam blocking filter called barracuda and that any emails @yahoo.com domain gets blocked.  How can I get around this?

Here is my email code:

```
$config['wordwrap'] = FALSE;
$config['mailtype'] = 'html'; 


$this->email->initialize($config);  

 $a=$this->load->view('cart/email',$data,true);
$this->email->from($data['email'], $data['fname'].' '.$data['lname']);
$this->email->to('order@abc.ca'); 
$this->email->subject('Your Order');
$this->email->message($a);  
$this->email->send();
  echo $this->email->print_debugger();
```

Answer (score 1):

If that is a hosting issue, there is not much we can do about it. You can use a different and more reliable SMTP provider, such as `Mandrill`. It works great and has an extremely easy API.

http://mandrill.com/

Comment: Would I be able to set the smtp config settings differently to bypass this problem?  See the problem is with only yahoo accounts.  I can't send email using a yahoo account from say a gmail account.

https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370?hl=en

Comment: It won't be an issue with Mandrill. You will be using Mandrill API after all.

Comment: Try:  $this->email->from('youremail@yourdomain.com', $data['fname'].' '.$data['lname']);  I know it looks weird, but it works. Here your host sees it as the email is going from their host, so they allow it. I'm having this issue myself, and that's the way to go. For now